# Is there a way to get disc space remaining using an SQL query on an Oracle database?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

We experienced a problem recently where the disc space ran low and some queries started giving unpredictable results. The root cause was that we'd take too many restore points and filled up the disc.

I'd like to be able to monitor this. My context is a big corporate, highly separated functional roles, so I only have access to the SQL query on the box.

My question is: **Is there a way to get disc space remaining using an SQL query on an Oracle database?**

Comment: Is the more fundamental issue that you have restore points sitting on a production server that have not been removed somewhere safe that would allow you to restore the db in the case of a failure?

Comment: How does one remove restore points to 'somewhere else' ?

Comment: OP, see http://gavinsoorma.com/2009/06/monitor-the-flashback-area-space-usage/ on how to monitor flashback space usage (where flashback files are stored). You do want to check them and raise alerts else you will experience problems. By wrong/unpredictable results is NOT one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/schema001.htm#ADMIN11568) at Managed Tablespace Alerts, notably this bit where you can monitor by two criteria with warning and critical thresholds.

```
    By percent full

For both warning and critical thresholds, when space used becomes greater than or equal to a percent of total space, an alert is issued.

    By free space remaining (in kilobytes (KB))

For both warning and critical thresholds, when remaining space falls below an amount in KB, an alert is issued. Free-space-remaining thresholds are more useful for very large tablespaces.
```